# package error in ssis but not bids

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I created an export to access package using the wizard (because why reinvent the wheel) using a view (i later found out views take forever to run) as the data source. i did some research and found out that it runs faster if i just take the query that builds the view and use that as the source. This runs fast in bids 2008 (3 seconds vs almost 30 minutes). So i put this on the job agent for sql server so we have an automated export of data, run it to test it, and it fails.

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.6000.34 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  11:43:31 AM  Error: 2017-10-31 12:04:09.50     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Destination - Etching_LookupView_Sink1Temperature [109]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E03.  End Error  Error: 2017-10-31 12:04:09.50     Code: 0xC0047022     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - Etching_LookupView_Sink1Temperature" (109) failed with error code 0xC0202009 while processing input "Destination Input" (122). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  11:43:31 AM  Finished: 12:04:09 PM  Elapsed:  1237.81 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

From the research i have done on this error code, it talks about casting, but i am not casting anything.

this is the query i was provided for the view.

```
SELECT     dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Date, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.EtchLot, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Part_Number, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Lot_Number, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Leadbond_Lot, 
                      dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Acid_Batch, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Operator_ID, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.WorkOrder, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Sink, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Num_Diodes, 
                      dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Number, AVG(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.[210Temperature]) AS AvgOf210Temperature, MAX(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.[210Temperature]) AS MaxOf210Temperature,
                       MIN(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.[210Temperature]) AS MinOf210Temperature, AVG(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.NitricTemperature) AS AvgOfNitricTemperature, 
                      MAX(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.NitricTemperature) AS MaxOfNitricTemperature, MIN(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.NitricTemperature) AS MinOfNitricTemperature, 
                      AVG(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.LeftRinseWaterTemperature) AS AvgOfLeftRinseWaterTemperature, MAX(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.LeftRinseWaterTemperature) 
                      AS MaxOfLeftRinseWaterTemperature, MIN(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.LeftRinseWaterTemperature) AS MinOfLeftRinseWaterTemperature, 
                      AVG(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.RightRinseWaterTemperature) AS AvgOfRightRinseWaterTemperature, MAX(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.RightRinseWaterTemperature) 
                      AS MaxOfRightRinseWaterTemperature, MIN(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.RightRinseWaterTemperature) AS MinOfRightRinseWaterTemperature, 
                      AVG(dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.RightRinseWaterResistivity) AS AvgOfRightRinseWaterResistivity, dbo.Etching_LookupView_LeadbondLots.RecipeName, 
                      dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Time_210_1, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Time_210_2, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Time_210_3, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Time_210_4, 
                      dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Time_Nitric_1, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Time_Nitric_2
FROM         dbo.Etching_Trace_Data INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime ON dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Leadbond_Lot = dbo.Etching_Meas_Runtime.LotNumber INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Etching_LookupView_LeadbondLots ON dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Leadbond_Lot = dbo.Etching_LookupView_LeadbondLots.Leadbond_lot
WHERE     (dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Date > '2017-08-01 00:00:00')
GROUP BY dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Date, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.EtchLot, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Part_Number, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Lot_Number, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Leadbond_Lot, 
                      dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Acid_Batch, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Operator_ID, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.WorkOrder, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Sink, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Num_Diodes, 
                      dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Number, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Time_210_1, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Time_210_2, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Time_210_3, 
                      dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Time_210_4, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Time_Nitric_1, dbo.Etching_Trace_Data.Etch_Time_Nitric_2, dbo.Etching_LookupView_LeadbondLots.RecipeName
```

Comment: Firstly: views don't take any longer to run than the SQL inside them. There's something else going on there. Secondly: there's nothing useful in your error message to give any clues (except to what actually failed). There are three main differences between running in BIDS and running in SQL Agent: 1. The user account that it runs under might be different; 2. It runs on the SQL server, not wherever BIDS is installed. 3. BIDS is always 32 bit, SQL Agent might be 64 bit.

Comment: The error message is complaining about the destination. What are you exporting to? excel? First try the screenshot at the bottom of the page here to force it to run in 32 bit: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2010/03/24/running-32-bit-ssis-in-a-64-bit-environment.aspx

Comment: Nick, when i was testing in bids it took like 30 minutes to validate the source while it was pointing to the view, i did some research and found a post https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/258901/ssis-views-as-data-source-very-poor-performance-or-ssis-hangs also, the account that is running for SQL agent is a domain admin. The sql agent is 64-bit. the destination is running  the ace 12.0 engine, to switch that to 32 bit, i will have to change to the jet 4.0 engine. (ok did that and now its complaining about permissions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up "fixing" my problem by rerunning the export wizard and using the query for the source instead of the view, and it executed just fine. my guess is i mucked something up while in BIDS that i wasn't aware of.

The importance of the query vs the view is that when SSIS tries to validate the view there is a major slowdown that causes the package to fail when run through the agent, but when you provide the query instead, it validates much faster.

The details are here:

> https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/258901/ssis-views-as-data-source-very-poor-performance-or-ssis-hangs

with the pertinent portion being

> Posted by Microsoft on 4/28/2008 at 2:45 PM
>   This is a know issue and the result of the current design.
>
> There are 2 ways to pull data from a view in OLE DB source:
>
> 1. Use "Table or view" access method
> 2. Use "SQL command" access method, and enter a query "select * from ***"
>
> A different execution plan is generated in the two approaches.
>
> The one used in the former is not as efficient as the latter.
>
> If you hit the performance issue when going with the first approach, you can switch to the second approach as a work around.
>
> We have also blogged this issue - >http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlperf/archive/2007/04/29/set-up-ole-db-source-to-read-from-view-efficiently.aspx.
>
> Since this is a 'By Design' item and we believe that there is a work around we will not be providing any change at this time. As a result we are closing the case associated with your submission. If you disagree, please feel free to re-submit.
>
> We appreciate your time, effort, and support of SSIS.

Comment: I've never ever experienced anything like that view issue you're seeing. (I'm sure you're experiencing it but it's very strange!). Not only that, you're saying that it stopped that error ocurring? Perhaps the error is due to a timeout. Anyway thanks fro returning with a detailed answer

Comment: I feel like the timeout was the issue as well. the super weird part was that i used the wizard and it took so long to validate creating it.